# Variable getting overwritten

Tags: java, spring-boot, dependency-injection, lombok

I've written some code using Spring Boot and Lombok. I've got two objects, `user` and `loggedInUser` both are based on `User.class`. I assign a different value to the each of the objects `userEmail` field. I got the following code. The `user` is what is in the request from the endpoint while the `loggedInUser` is the user performing the request.

This is the `User.class`:

```
@Component
@Data
public class User {    
    private String userEmail;
}
```

This is the class where I'm using `User.class`

```
private User user;

private User loggedInUser;

private SearchParameters searchParameters;

public UserController(
        User user,
        User loggedInUser,
        SearchParameters searchParameters, {

    this.user = user;
    this.loggedInUser = loggedInUser;
    this.searchParameters = searchParameters;
}

@GetMapping(value = "${apiVersion.v_1}" + "/users")
public ResponseEntity getUsers(
        @RequestParam("userEmail") String userEmail,
        @RequestParam("direction") String direction,
        @RequestParam("limit") String limit) {

    Jws<Claims> jwsClaims = (Jws<Claims>) SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication().getPrincipal();
    loggedInUser.setUserEmail(jwsClaims.getBody().getSubject()); //From a JWT the logged in user's e-mail is picked up. In this case joe@example.com
    log.info("loggedInUser.getUserEmail #1: " + loggedInUser.getUserEmail());

    user.setUserEmail(userEmail); // From the request parameters the email is that will be used for the search is picked up. In this case smith@example.com
    searchParameters.setDirection(direction); //Can be "u" or "d" that corresponds to "SELECT * FROM user_tbl WHERE < user.getEmail()" or "SELECT * FROM user_tbl WHERE > user.getEmail()" in the SQL that will run in another class 
    searchParameters.setLimit(limit); //An integer that will limit the number of returned results from the user_tbl
    log.info("loggedInUser.getUserEmail #2: " + loggedInUser.getUserEmail());

    //The search is done in another class that is taking user.getEmail() as an argument and returns a List of users
```

return (new ResponseEntity(users, headers, HttpStatus.OK));
    }

It gives me the following output.

```
loggedInUser.getUserEmail #1: joe@example.com
loggedInUser.getUserEmail #2: smith@example.com
```

I would have thought that `user` and `loggedInUser` are two separate objects since they have different names and that the dependency injection is instantiate a new object each time but it seems like `user` is overwriting `loggedInUser`. What is it I'm missing here?

Comment: Is it possible that `user` and `loggedInUser` are actually the same object?  You could use your debugger to check that.

Comment: *and that the dependency injection is instantiate a new object each time*: why do you think that's the case? Spring beans are singletons by default.

Comment: @JBNizet Sorry I might have mixed that up. Does that mean that `user` and `loggedInUser` is the same object?

Comment: Yes. That's what that means.

Comment: @JBNizet OK. Is the best way to use to different classes for the two different objects?

Comment: I think your whole design doesn't make sense, and that you should read about Spring to understand what you're doing. What is `loggedInUser` supposed to represent? I could understand if that was a Spring bean with request or session scope. But definitely not a singleton. But what is `user` supposed to represent? Why is it a Spring bean?

Comment: @JBNizet. I added some more details to post. The `user` is the information being requested while `loggedInUser` is the user requesting the information. In this chase `joe@example.com` is requesting information for `smith@example.com`.

Comment: They should not be Spring beans, and should not be fields of your controller. You need to realize that a single controller instance is serving, concurrently, all the requests of your actual users.